# Rails app works fine normally, but not in rpsec test. "nil class"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

When a contract gets created, it takes a Unit, User and Discount and uses those param items (models) to generate an Invoice.

Everything works fine in the browser. But when running a spec, I'm getting `undefined method 'value' for nil:NilClass [/app/models/option.rb:19:in 'get_from_database'`

Line 18-20 of Option.rb. This is a model for getting site options (configurable by the admin) from the database. Works fine normally (browser tests).

```
def self.get_from_database(name)
  $option[name] = self.find_by_name(name).send('value')
end
```

And it's being called from Contract.rb:

```
def start_date=(date)
    self[:start_date] = Date.strptime(date, Option.get_from_database('short_date'))
end
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error? If I comment out this line and re-run the spec test, I get another `nil:NilClass` error from another class method call.

I've just started working with rspec, so I'm sure I'm missing something. NOTE: The first test works, the second doesn't.

```
require 'spec_helper'

module ContractSpecHelper
  def contract_params
    {  :start_date => "08/09/2012",
       :client_id => '1', 
       :pay_interval_id => '1', 
       :billing_day => "1",
       :prorated => '1',
       :require_next => "1",
       :include_today => "1",
       :unit_id => '45',
       :due => "1" }
  end
end

describe 'Contract' do
  include ContractSpecHelper

  before :each do
    @contract = Contract.new
  end

  describe '#new' do
    it "requires a unit, user, and pay interval id" do
      @contract.should_not be_valid
    end

    it "creates an invoice once saved" do
      @contract.attributes = contract_params
      @contract.save

      @contract.should have(1).invoice
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Maybe method 'value' is creating by metaprogramming and it works fine in application because method was create somewhere in application, but in rspec it is not happening. So to test this snippet you need to set up environment appropriately.

Comment: So should I `include` all related files such as Option.rb, Invoice.rb, Unit.rb, etc.? If so, what's the best method of doing this? If not, then how should I setup the environment correctly?

Comment: Apparently `find_by_name(name)` is returning nil.  Where is this method being called in your program?  What is the value of `name` when it is called?  Is there such an object in your **test** database?

Comment: Option.rb extends ActiveRecord, so `find_by_name` is the basic ActiveRecord method to find a record by name. When a Contract is being created, the `start_date=(date)` method (shown above) is executed. This is where the `get_from_database` method is called from.

Also, the test DB is raked and loaded. Basically duplicates the development database.

Comment: OK, is there an Option object with the name "short_date" in your **test** database?  What is the output if you run `rails c test` and then `Option.find_by_name('short_date')`?

Comment: I get an error. I did a few tests with `rescue` and you're absolutely right, the DB is empty. I had tried `rake db:seed RAILS_ENV='test'`, but apparently that doesn't work. How can I clone data (structure is already there) from dev to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears be that `Option.find_by_name(name)` is returning nil.

The most likely cause of this is that you're not populating the options table in the test environment. Either change your code to handle Option record not existing, or use fixtures/factory_girl/machinist/ before block (etc) to create option records in your test environment.

(To answer your other question, your environment should be loaded in your spec_helper. You shouldn't need to manually include your rails models into your rspec specs.)

Comment: Is there a way to simply clone data (not structure) from dev to test?

Comment: One way is to dump your development db data to `db/seeds.db` and then use `rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=test` to load the data into your test environment. See https://github.com/rhalff/seed_dump for a way to do this. Ideally though you should either create your test environment data in your tests, or through fixtures, etc. You should expect your test environment to be volatile.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! This has fixed the issue and I've learned a lot about rspec in the process. I understand your comment about leaving  the test DB blank, it makes perfect sense now. Thanks again!